# fql.query on test users returns empty array , why ?

Tags: php, testing, facebook-fql

Is there any restriction on test users when it comes to fql or photos? 
i have test user i uploaded him with photos to album , also the album is set to public
now when i run this fql :

```
$user_albums_photos = $facebook->api(array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => 'SELECT src,src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me())'
     ));
```

.im getting empty array .
the wired thing is when i do it with real use (me) every thing is working and i get full array list.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to first request the `user_photos` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/). This is required even if the privacy of the photos is set to "Public".